# How can i remove extra "fluff " from an array after using pandas to parse and excel file

Tags: python, pandas

Im having trouble with my code. I'm making a macro that will parse data from an excel sheet. Ideally id like it to get the row number from the sheet and using that row number grab the cell value on its same row in another column. This is the Code I have so far:

```
k = 0
while (k<fileCount):
    rowNumbertemp.append(xlEntries.loc[xlEntries['StockNumber'] == partNumbers[k]].index.to_numpy())
    rowNumber.append((rowNumbertemp[k]))  # Append only the first row number found
    specNametemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"Pat's Proposed Change"]
    specName.append(specNametemp)
    specValuetemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"StringValue"]
    specValue.append(specValuetemp)
    k = k + 1
```

I get no errors but my print out comes out looking like this :

```
`7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2590    10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2065    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2383    7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2591    10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2066    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2379    7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2380    7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2381    7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2587    10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2588    10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2589    10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2062    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2063    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2064    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2384    7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2385    7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2592    10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2593    10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2067    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 163    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), Series([], Name: StringValue, dtype: object), 2066    15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object, 2383    7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
Name: StringValue, dtype: object]`
```

When ideally id like it to look like ::

```
`7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz
10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz
10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz`
```

Ive tried using lines of code such as

```
rowNumber.remove([])
and 
specnumber.remove('dtype')
```

both of which just errors out.

please give mme any and all guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you want comes after a tab on each line, which means after you can use `.split('\t')[1]` on a line to take everything right of the tab. `.split('\t')` makes an array of the sections tab characters were separating (in this case, index 0 is everything left of the tab, and index 1 is everything right of the tab), and the `[1]` at the end gives you everything in index 1 (aka everything right of the tab).

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work for me sice these are lists and its giving me an error. When i tried to research how to fix it it said that lists dont ahve access to this functionality. "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: @JaivenMcIntosh I don't have enough information to know exactly what's being stored where and what you're printing out, but you wouldn't be able to use `.split()` on the entire output. If each line of what you printed is a string, you can use `.split('\t')[1]` on each line one at a time to remove the the fluff. Otherwise, you could check every array element for the fluff, but I think it's best to temporarily print out every value before you add it to the array until you identify where the fluff is being added, then just have your code remove it before it's added to the array.